# Bypassing the ItemSend Event in Outlook

Tags: c#, email, outlook, event-handling

We have developed a C# Outlook Add-in for a Client that allows them to File emails into their Data Management System (i.e. trap email data, enter in some additional metadata as well as where in the DMS it's to be stored). This can be done on emails in their Inbox (File) or on emails they are sending/forwarding (Send and File). This all works great.

The issue is that our Client also uses another Add-in that is trapping the ItemSend Event and blocking our Add-in from completing when they try to Send and File an email. After filing the email data into their DMS, we send it by calling Outlook's MailItem.Send method, which raises the ItemSend Event, causing their Add-in to pop up and halt ours from working. We can't have them disable that Add-in, as they use its other features for their business process, nor do we have access to its code to disable the ItemSend Event Handling.

Is there a way to send the email without raising the ItemSend Event?

Answer (score 0):

You are free to use a low-level API - Extended MAPI from managed languages (C# in your case). Nobody forbids doing so. Outlook is just a big wrapper around that API (and Redemption too). See [MAPI and .Net](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2009/04/03/mapi-and-net.aspx) for more information.